# Is there alternative way to JavascriptInterface of Webview on Chrome Custom Tabs?

Tags: chrome-custom-tabs

I am using JavascriptInterface of Webview.
Is it possible on Chrome Custom Tabs?
Or
Is there alternative method of that?

Answer (score 2):

No. CustomTabs do *not* allow apps to interact with web page contents for privacy reasons. Though you can measure how fast the pages load with `CustomTabsCallback`.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I'll try change my design to use CustomTabCallback.

Comment: Great! Feel free to send us feedback about CustomTabsCallback. We usually react faster and better if issues/suggestions are filed via the Chromium Issue Tracker - just use the link at the bottom of the readme: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/custom-tabs-client

Comment: Egor, is it possible to make a POST request with custom tabs?

Comment: It is certainly possible to make AJAX POST requests from the web page being opened in CustomTabs, just like with any webpage opened in Chrome. However, it is not possible to open a custom tab with POST, we only support method GET.